# How to retrieve arraylist from firebase database in recyclerview in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to populate my recyclerview from the data stored on firebase database.I tried searching net but most the examples have simple json tree structure and my Json db has following format: [image]

and my android code is as follows:

**ModelClass.java**

```
package com.example.android.directory;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ModelClass {

    private ArrayList<CategoryList> categoryList;

    public ModelClass(ArrayList<CategoryList> categoryList) {
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }

    public ArrayList<CategoryList> getCategoryList() {
        return categoryList;
    }

    public void setCategoryList(ArrayList<CategoryList> categoryList) {
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }



    public  static class CategoryList{
        public int Category_id;
        public String Category_name;
        public ArrayList<String>Emails;
        public ArrayList<String>Epabx;
        public ArrayList<String>Category_Fax;
        public ArrayList<Persons> persons;

        public CategoryList(int category_id, String category_name, ArrayList<String> emails,
                            ArrayList<String> epabx, ArrayList<String> category_Fax, ArrayList<Persons> persons) {
            Category_id = category_id;
            Category_name = category_name;
            Emails = emails;
            Epabx = epabx;
            Category_Fax = category_Fax;
            this.persons = persons;
        }

        public int getCategory_id() {
            return Category_id;
        }

        public void setCategory_id(int category_id) {
            Category_id = category_id;
        }

        public String getCategory_name() {
            return Category_name;
        }

        public void setCategory_name(String category_name) {
            Category_name = category_name;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getEmails() {
            return Emails;
        }

        public void setEmails(ArrayList<String> emails) {
            Emails = emails;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getEpabx() {
            return Epabx;
        }

        public void setEpabx(ArrayList<String> epabx) {
            Epabx = epabx;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getCategory_Fax() {
            return Category_Fax;
        }

        public void setCategory_Fax(ArrayList<String> category_Fax) {
            Category_Fax = category_Fax;
        }

        public ArrayList<Persons> getPersons() {
            return persons;
        }

        public void setPersons(ArrayList<Persons> persons) {
            this.persons = persons;
        }
    }

    public static class Persons{
        private int Person_ID;
        private String Name;
        private String Designation;
        private String Office_Phone;
        private String Residence_Phone;
        private String VOIP;
        private String Address;
        private ArrayList<String>Fax;
        private String Ext;

        public Persons(int person_ID, String name, String designation, String office_Phone,
                       String residence_Phone, String VOIP, String address, ArrayList<String> fax, String ext) {
            Person_ID = person_ID;
            Name = name;
            Designation = designation;
            Office_Phone = office_Phone;
            Residence_Phone = residence_Phone;
            this.VOIP = VOIP;
            Address = address;
            Fax = fax;
            Ext = ext;
        }

        public int getPerson_ID() {
            return Person_ID;
        }

        public void setPerson_ID(int person_ID) {
            Person_ID = person_ID;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }

        public String getDesignation() {
            return Designation;
        }

        public void setDesignation(String designation) {
            Designation = designation;
        }

        public String getOffice_Phone() {
            return Office_Phone;
        }

        public void setOffice_Phone(String office_Phone) {
            Office_Phone = office_Phone;
        }

        public String getResidence_Phone() {
            return Residence_Phone;
        }

        public void setResidence_Phone(String residence_Phone) {
            Residence_Phone = residence_Phone;
        }

        public String getVOIP() {
            return VOIP;
        }

        public void setVOIP(String VOIP) {
            this.VOIP = VOIP;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return Address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            Address = address;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getFax() {
            return Fax;
        }

        public void setFax(ArrayList<String> fax) {
            Fax = fax;
        }

        public String getExt() {
            return Ext;
        }

        public void setExt(String ext) {
            Ext = ext;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.android.directory.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">
    </include>


    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearchMain"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_search"
        android:hint="@string/searchtext_hint"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#233343"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/inputSearchMain"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_Main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**cardview_row_main.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView_mainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/govt_logo_Main"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#233343"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nextMain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/next"
                android:background="#1DE9B6"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>



        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.directory;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference databaseCategory;
    private ArrayList<ModelClass.CategoryList> mcategoryset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        databaseCategory= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Main);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass,CategoryViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, CategoryViewHolder>(
                ModelClass.class, R.layout.cardview_row_main,CategoryViewHolder.class,databaseCategory
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, ModelClass model, int position) {
                viewHolder.category_name.setText(model.getCategoryList().get);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

How should i retrieve "Category_name" from the firebase database in this activity?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Get instance of DatabaseReference**

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseApplication.getFirebaseDbInstance();

**2 .Set Firebase db listener**

mDatabase.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener()

```
{
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
    {
     //empty  
    }
};
```

DataSnapshot will give you list of data

Answer (score 0):

Use this

Define the arraylist locally.

```
ArrayList<ModelClass > md = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then call this

```
    mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Getting the data from snapshot
                 md= postSnapshot.getValue(ModelClass .class);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
```

After that pass your arraylist into recycler adapter.

Comment: What should i write here: " viewHolder.category_name.setText(model.getCategoryList().get); " then?

Comment: Your code is giving incompatible types error at " md= postSnapshot.getValue(ModelClass .class); "

Answer (score 0):

```
 Query nm=d.orderByChild("pincode").equalTo(query);
         nm.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> objectsGTypeInd = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
                Map<String, Object> objectHashMap = dataSnapshot.getValue(objectsGTypeInd);
                ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(objectHashMap.values());
                Log.d("yahape",objectArrayList.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

u must do this it will work same for database reference also.it worked for me fine.